# How do I remove orange (rust?) stains from white elements?

Tags: cleaning

I'm building with some yard sale Lego, and have several elements that have orange stains on them. If I had to guess, I'd say something seeped onto the bricks while they were in storage. At this point I'll probably bury them inside my MOC, but I'm curious to know if there is a method to unblemish white Lego elements?

Comment: I guess the first step would be to identify what the stuff actually is (the only idea that comes to mind being cat urine, since an unguarded box of small LEGO parts could be mistaken for a litter box by some); and then whether is comes of or not - I supposed you've tried [regular cleaning options](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/124/99) already? And are you sure it's orange spots, not simply [sun-yellowed bricks](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/83/99)?

Comment: If it's really rust stains, [oxalic acid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxalic_acid) may be worth trying...

Comment: So far I tried a warm soapy water scrub with a soft toothbrush... Still have orange stains. Thankfully, there was no litter box aroma. I shy away from those yard sales. ;)

Comment: Does it happen to look anything like [this](http://i.imgur.com/ZgxBodJ.jpg)?

Comment: @Ambo100 Quite simular. Sorry, I should have posted an image. I'll do that soon.

Comment: UPDATE: Buried the bricks in question while building for this weekends display. Will need to wait to disassemble MOC before a pic can be posted.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try with toothpaste and a toothbrush as toothpaste is one of the mildest polishers.