# LEGO Cleaning/Sterilisation

Tags: cleaning

I am just looking to see if anyone knows of a LEGO product that exists that allows you to sterilise your LEGO using your dishwasher.

Thanks

Comment: Please take a look at [Is it safe to wash LEGO pieces in the dishwasher](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/57/56) and [LEGO cleaning techniques and tools](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/124/56) - In summary: LEGO recommend using a dishwasher or washing machine to clean bricks, and recommend a mild bleach if you want to disinfect them.

Answer (score 2):

There is no LEGO product specifically meant for this, however you can use third-party laundry-bags, or even a pillow-case, to wash your LEGO in the dishwasher or washing-machine. If you use the dishwasher, make sure you use the top-rack, and the water should be luke-warm. You can use mild soap.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the generally accepted method, but when I cleaned my old pieces, I put them in a washbasin in soapy water and then used a soft toothbrush to clean them off. After that I just air-dried them. Most of the pieces became nice and clean after this but old discoloration and scratches won't go away.

Using hot water (dishwasher or not) and / or hot air may warp the pieces.